# Installing Win7 SP1, Dual Boot with Ubuntu, using GRUB and not Win Sys Reserved partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

So I have a 240SSD 20gb for Ubuntu (Active) with the GRUB bootloader on it. Just root partition, no home, no swap. And I have a 200gb Windows 7 partition (Primary as well but not active). My issue is that since I don't have a system reserved partition for windows 7 and it is also not active, I'm not able to install the SP1 update for it. My question is can I just make it active, install the update then I'm guessing I would have to boot from my USB Live Ubuntu flash drive in order to rebuild/fix GRUB. Is my way of thinking correct? Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Active in Windows is boot flag everywhere else. Windows only boots from, installs to, or repairs the primary NTFS partition with the boot flag. Grub does not use boot flag, so always keep it on the NTFS primary partition with boot files. Best to backup partition table, after any resize, so you can restore it if needed. Windows has always deleted (or just ignored) any Linux logical partitions. It just leaves it out of partition table and has to be restored to table. Data is still there. `sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > PTsda.txt` Save file to another drive/device. You may have to reinstall grub.

Comment: okay thanks, I saved the partition table like you said. I don't think I need to create a system restore partition on the windows side, but just make it active temporarily in order to update it and then boot back to Linux using live USB flash drive and reinstall grub. I'll post the changes later. Ty

Answer (score 0):

So I went ahead and clicked on the Windows 7 partition under Disk management in Win7 environment and set it as Active. I was then able to perform the SP1 update on it. The GRUB2 bootloader was not affected at all and now I'm on Linux Ubuntu with no problem. I think the only thing to denote is that the Active partition now is Win7 instead of Linux. However, the same effect of dual effect still holds. Hence; mission accomplished with no problem. Ty anyways. :)